# Determine maximum and minimum pixel value to draw bounding box

Tags: python, image-processing

Given an image with semantic map,

[image]

[image]

In python, How can I draw a bounding-box around the person standing for instance?

I've done some research and understood that I need to choose the maximum and minimum pixel value to get the bounding box information. But I don't understand how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Redraw the object you want to box in unique for that semantic map color. For instance I've used green:

[image: semantic map]

2. Run following script:

.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

IMAGE = 't5XM4.png'
IMAGE_MAP = 'Gz8b7.png'
IMAGE_OUTPUT = 'Result.png'
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
OFFSET = 10

image_map = Image.open(IMAGE_MAP)
image = Image.open(IMAGE)
pixels = image_map.load()
size_sm = image_map.size
size = image.size
ratio = (size_sm[0]/size[0], size_sm[1]/size[1])
x_list = []
y_list = []

for x in range(size_sm[0]):
    for y in range(size_sm[1]):
        if pixels[x, y] == GREEN:
            x_list.append(x)
            y_list.append(y)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.rectangle(((min(x_list)/ratio[0]-OFFSET, min(y_list)/ratio[1]-OFFSET),
                (max(x_list)/ratio[0]+OFFSET,max(y_list)/ratio[1]+OFFSET)),
               width=5, outline=GREEN)
image.save(IMAGE_OUTPUT, 'PNG')
```

3. You've got following image at the end:

[image: result image with bounding box]

Comment: Great. In step one, how did you redraw the object?

Comment: Mind asking additional question? I would like to apply noise (cover the person) inside the box. I know how to do that, but In your script how can I get x1, y1,x2,y2,c ??

Comment: These values are stands for (x1,y1), (x2,y2): (min(x_list)/ratio[0]-OFFSET, min(y_list)/ratio[1]-OFFSET)(max(x_list)/ratio[0]+OFFSET,max(y_list)/ratio[1]+OFFSET))

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. You mean `min(x_list)/ratio[0]-OFFSET, min(y_list)/ratio[1]-OFFSET)(max(x_list)/ratio[0]+OFFSET,max(y_list)/ratio[1]+OFFSET)` is equivalent to `(x1,y1), (x2,y2)` ?

Comment: x1 = min(x_list)/ratio[0]-OFFSET, y1 = min(y_list)/ratio[1]-OFFSET, x2 = max(x_list)/ratio[0]+OFFSET, y2 = max(y_list)/ratio[1]+OFFSET

Comment: final question. Why applying the same technique to other (different) images returns `draw.rectangle(((min(x_list)/ratio[0]-OFFSET, min(y_list)/ratio[1]-OFFSET),ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence ` ?? Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely GREEN color was not found in the image.

Comment: This what I thought, but than did the 1 step you mentioned (the redrawing part) and yet I got the error. Quite confusing.

Comment: Can you send me the image you have problem with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185906/discussion-between-user3641381-and-alderven).